# swagger3 cannot input multiple values for list parameter

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox, swagger-3.0

spring boot 2.x, i added `springfox-boot-starter 3.0.0` and `@EnableOpenApi` to use swagger3.

i have following controller

```
@DeleteMapping("/rate")
public void deleteRate(@ApiParam(value = "dc id") @RequestParam(required = false) Integer dcId,
                       @ApiParam(value = "rate id")
                       @RequestParam(required = false) List<Integer> dcrIdList) {
```

however, for parameter `List<Integer>` in swagger, it is integer rather than an array/list, it looks like:

[image]

it should be multiple inputs such that i can enter multiple values for array/list, right?

how can i input multiple values for `list` in swagger3? if i type multiple values separated by comma in one input, swagger3 give me error tip.